# How to generate PDF with current pageweb in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, itext

I want to to generate a PDF with all my tables, I searched on google and I found code above and work but for o image and some text:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser
Partial Class VBCode
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    End Sub


    Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
        ' Verifies that the control is rendered 

    End Sub
    Protected Sub btnPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf")
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        Me.Page.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        htmlparser.Parse(sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
        Response.[End]()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is page with code and in desgin mode is that:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="VBCode.aspx.vb" Inherits="VBCode" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/_B28NJpJ61hA/TdgnS7lh7mI/AAAAAAAAAi4/oLTicIRgEIw/FinalLogo.png" /></div>
<div><b>Export Webpage with images to pdf using itextsharp dll</b>
<br />

</div><br />
<div>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnPDF" runat="server" Text="Export to PDF" OnClick="btnPDF_Click"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to generate pdf withh my asp table and what i want in him but doesn't work, if you have an alternative please help me....

if i put my code with all codes give me that error:

> Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

On line: htmlparser.Parse(sr)

Comment: Please give us the link where you found that code.

Comment: Also, `HTMLWorker` is deprecated in favor of `XMLWorker`.

Comment: The exception you are seeing is being thrown by the .Net framework itself, I believe by `System.Uri`. If you inspect the contents of `sw` you'll find your actual HTML that you are asking to be parsed and something in there broken.